# Need to look up key using string in a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Class

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to use a list pulled from sql, list is built from

```
 Dictionary<Int32, String> measurementTypes = this.GetIndicatorTypes(MeasurementTypeFilter.All);
```

is ther a way to retrive the key using the string.
Something like

```
TypeID = measurementTypes.contains("GEN");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it'll be slow (i.e. O(n)), but you can do:

```
var keys = measurementTypes.Where(pair => pair.Value == "GEN")
                           .Select(pair => pair.Key);
```

That will give you a *sequence* of pairs which have the given value. There could be 0, 1 or many matches. From there you can pick the first matching key etc - whatever you need. Using `First` or `Single` would be appropriate if you think there will be at least one or exactly one; `FirstOrDefault` would return 0 if there were no matches, which may not be appropriate for you if 0 could also be a valid key.

Comment: @Jon: Wouldn't there be a way to use `DefaultIfEmpty` to mimic the functionality of `FirstOrDefault`, except with the ability to specify the default value?

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the best approach. I went ahead and deleted my answer as doing `First` or `FirstOrDefault` would not be failsafe.

Comment: Something like `var key = measurementTypes.Where(pair => pair.value == "GEN").DefaultIfEmpty(ImpossibleValue).First().Key;`

Comment: @Steven: I think I'd prefer to convert it to an `int?` sequence, to be honest. That's a more appropriate representation, IMO.

Comment: @Jon: I can't argue with that, since we can use `null` instead of arbitrarily declaring some value to be invalid.  What would the code for that look like?

Comment: Let me answer my own question: `var key = measurementTypes.Where(pair => pair.Value == "Bye").Select( pair => (int?)pair.Key).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeID = measurementTypes.Values.Where(v => v.Equals("GEN")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: No. This should return the actual value.

Comment: Right, but he wants the key, not the value.

Comment: Yeah, but not everyone is a robot.  Jon Skeet is still a prototype; it's the next version that will take over the Earth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to help you out there.

```
TypeID = measurementTypes.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == "GEN")
                         .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
                         .FirstOrDefault()
```